# HTML内にscriptを記載して思っているようにしたいのですが、どうしても上手くいきません

Tags: javascript, html, css

以下の四つを実現出来るようにしたいのですが、scriptタグの中にどのようなコードを書けば良いかわかりません。どなたかご教授ください。

##### 実現したいこと

1つ目: 名前とニックネームを3回追記したらボタンを非表示（削除ではないのでDisplayではないとは思いますが）にし、それ以降は追記できない。

2つ目: tableタグとそれに関連するタグを利用し、登録した 名前 と ニックネーム を最大3人分までテーブル表示できるようにする。

3つ目: 名前とニックネームの追加時、各行の右端に削除ボタンを出力させて、ボタンをクリックすると
ボタンがある行を削除する処理を作成する。

4つ目: データを3件登録して追加ボタンを消すようにしたが、削除ボタンでデータが削除され3件未満になった場合は追加ボタンを再表示させ、3件になるまで追加し直せるようにする。

##### 現状のHTMLコード

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>アカウント登録</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <style>
          .base {
            margin: 2% 7% 0;
            height: 500px;
            background: blue;
            padding: 5% 10%;
            box-shadow: 5px 9px 8px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
          }
          input {
            width: 300px;
            height: 40px;
            font-size: large;
          }
          #tuikaBtn {
            background: green;
          }
          h1 {
            font-family: serif;
          }
          .form-control::placeholder {
              color: #cacaca;
              opacity: 1;
          }
          table {
            border-collapse: collapse; 
          }

          th,td {
            border: 1px solid #312929;
            padding: 5px 10px;
          }
          .card {
            width: 100%;
            height: 350px;
          }
          .back{
            padding: 30px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
          }
          .form-group{
            margin: 10px 0 15px 0px;
          }
          #result {
            font-size: 120%;
            margin: 10;
            margin: 10px 20px;
            padding: 10px 5px 20px;
            margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
          }

          .row .card{
            color: red;
          }

          .card{
            color: blue;
            display: block;
            position: relative;
          }

          #modal{
            display: none;
            margin:1.5em auto 0;
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 50%;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            position: fixed;
            border-radius: 5px;
          }

          #overLay{
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 120%;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
          }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="base container">
          <div class="row">
            <h1>アカウント登録</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="card" id="card">
              <div class="card-block">
                <form id="form-area" class="form-inline" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <input id="namae" name="namae" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="名前">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input id="nickname" name="nickname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ニックネーム">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input id="tuikaBtn" type="button" name="touroku" value="追加">
                    </div>

                </form>
                <div id="tuikaMoto">

                </div>
                <div id="result"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>  
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="overLay">
      </div>
        <script>
          
let result = document.getElementById('result'); 　 
let display = document.getElementById("tuikaBtn"); 
　
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {　　
    display.addEventListener('click', function () {

        
let namae = document.getElementById("namae");
let nickname = document.getElementById("nickname");

    if (namae.value === "" || nickname.value === "") { return false; }
    if (window.confirm(namae.value + "さん " + nickname.value + "を登録します。よろしいですか？")) {
result.innerHTML += "<br>" + namae.value + ": " + nickname.value;
}else { return false; }

alert(namae.value + 'さん' + nickname.value + 'にて登録しました。');

result.value = `${namae},${nickname}`; 
if(namae.value == "" || nickname.value == "") return false;
})
})
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 「どうしても上手くいきません。」とのことですが、ブラウザの開発者ツールに何かエラーは出ていないでしょうか？

Comment: やりたいことの 1 から 4 のどこまで自分で実装できているのですか？ ほとんどできてないように見えますが。(ほぼ丸投げで、コードを書いてくれと言っているように見えますが)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div>
            <label for="name">名前：</label><br />
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" size="30" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="nickname">ニックネーム：</label><br />
            <input id="nickname" name="nickname" type="text" size="30" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type='button' id="tuikaBtn" value='追加'>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <table id="tuikamoto" border="1"></table>
    
    <script>
        let tuikaBtn = document.getElementById('tuikaBtn');
        
        count = 0;
        tuikaBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (count < 3) {
                let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
                let nickname = document.getElementById('nickname').value;
                
                if (name !== ' ' && nickname !== ' ') {
                    let cofirm = confirm(name + 'さん' + nickname + 'を登録します。よろしいですか？');
                
                    if (confirm) {
                        let result = document.getElementById('result');
                        result.innerHTML +=　'<p>' + name + 'さん' + nickname + 'にて登録しました。</p>';
                        alert(name + 'さん' + nickname + 'にて登録しました。');
                        count++;
                        
                        if (count === 3) {
                                tuikaBtn.style.display = 'none';
                        }
                
                        // テーブルに追加
                        let table = document.getElementById('tuikamoto');
                        let row = table.insertRow(-1);
                        let cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);
                        let cell2 = row.insertCell(-1);
                        let cell3 = row.insertCell(-1);
                        cell1.innerHTML = name;
                        cell2.innerHTML = nickname;
                
                        // 削除ボタンを作成
                        deleteBtn = document.createElement('input');
                        deleteBtn.type = 'button';
                        deleteBtn.value = '削除';
                        cell3.appendChild(deleteBtn);
                        deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                            deleteRow(this);
                        });
                    }               
                } else {
                    alert('名前とニックネームを入力してください。')
                }
            } else {
                alert('３回登録済です。');
            }
        });
        
        function deleteRow(btn) {
            let row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
            row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
            count--;
            
            if (count < 3) {
                tuikaBtn.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```